# faster way to append value

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, append

Suppose I have a big list of float values and I want to select only some of them looking at an other array:

```
result = []
for x,s in zip(xlist, slist):
    if f(s): result.append(x)
```

at the begin of the loop I can have a rough estimation of how many entries will pass the `f` selection

now this is very slow, I've tried to change `list` to `array` but looking only at appending I get slower

```
def f(v):
    for ii in a: v.append(ii)
a = range(int(1E7))
v = []
t = time(); f(v); print time()-t # -> 1.3
v = array.array('i')
t = time(); f(v); print time()-t # -> 3.4
```

I need to be faster because this loop is really slow in my program. can `numpy.array` help me? There is no `append` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the first sentence in your question, you want to select values based on the values in another list or array.

In numpy you can use indexing to get selected values from an array. I use [Boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean) in the example. This avoids the need to append values to an existing array, but gives you a copy of the selected values as an array.
You can combine multiple conditions using the `&` or `|` operator, [logic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) from numpy or your own functions.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: size = int(1E7)

In [3]: ar = np.arange(size)

In [4]: ar2 = np.random.randint(100, size=size)

In [5]: %timeit ar[(ar2 > 50) & (ar2 < 70) | (ar2 == 42)]
10 loops, best of 3: 249 ms per loop
```

If you need every selection in a separate array based on different conditions (or ranges as given in the comment) you can do something like this:

```
conditions = [(10, 20), (20, 50)] # min, max as tuples in a list
results = {}
for condition in conditions:
    selection = ar[(ar2 > condition[0]) & (ar2 < condition[1])]
    # do something with the selection ?
    results[condition] = selection
print results
```

will give you something like that

```
{(20, 50): array([      2,       6,       7, ..., 9999993, 9999997, 9999998]),
 (10, 20): array([      1,       3,      66, ..., 9999961, 9999980, 9999999])}
```

You should avoid looping over a numpy array in general, but instead use vectorized functions to manipulate your arrays.

Comment: ok, this sounds good. Suppose now I've a lot of selections. If the value pass `selection1`, put it in `ar1`, if pass `selection2` put in `ar2`, .... Selections are similar to `10 < x <= 20`, `20 < x <= 50`, ...

Comment: @wiso I adapted  the example.

Comment: thank you, but this is not what I've asked in my comment. As output I need different collections, one for `10<x<=20`, the second for `20<x<=50`, ...

Comment: @wiso hope this is want you asked now

Comment: yes, your solution is easy, the point is that you have to loop over the data for every selections, and this is not optimal

Comment: The important point is that you don't have to loop over the elements of the array. looping over a few conditions should be no problem (and could be replaced by a list comprehension). Please give a full working example so I (or we) can give an answer (answers) considering some alternatives and benchmark them.

Comment: you are right. I've oversimplified my problem: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686847/fast-categorization-binning

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better numpy solution to this, but in pure-python you can try iterators:

```
from itertools import izip

xlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
slist = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]

def f(n):
    return n

results = (x for x,s in izip(xlist, slist) if f(s))

# results is an iterator--you don't have values yet
# and no extra memory is consumed
# you can retrieve results one by one with iteration
# or you can exhaust all values and store in a list

assert list(results)==[2,4,8]

# you can use an array too
# import array
# a = array.array('i', results)
```

You can also combine this approach with numpy arrays to see if it is faster. See the [`fromiter` constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.htm).

However if you can restructure your code to use iterators, you can avoid ever having to generate a full list and thus avoid using `append` at all.

It goes without saying, too, that you should see if you can speed up your `f()` filtering function because it's called once for every element.

Answer (score 1):

Try a deque: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque

From the python docs:

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction.
>
> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation.

On my system (I use a range of 1e6 due to my limited memory):

```
def f(v):
    for ii in a: v.append(ii)
a = range(int(1E6))
v = []
t = time(); f(v); print time()-t # -> .12
v = array.array('i')
t = time(); f(v); print time()-t # -> .25
v = collections.deque()
t = time(); f(v); print time()-t # -> .11
```