# fast categorization (binning)

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, binning

I've a huge number of entries, every one is a float number. These data `x` are accesible with an iterator. I need to classify all the entries using selection like `10<y<=20`, `20<y<=50`, .... where `y` are data from an other iterables. The number of entries is much more than the number of selections. At the end I want a dictionary like:

```
{ 0: [all events with 10<x<=20],
  1: [all events with 20<x<=50], ... }
```

or something similar. For example I'm doing:

```
for x, y in itertools.izip(variable_values, binning_values):
    thebin = binner_function(y)
    self.data[tuple(thebin)].append(x)
```

in general `y` is multidimensional.

This is very slow, is there a faster solution, for example with numpy? I think the problem cames from the `list.append` method I'm using and not from the `binner_function`

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy.histogram()`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: Does binner_function have to be general?  If you posted the implementation of it, we might be able to write a more efficient version of this, possibly with a dict/list comprehension.

Comment: `numpy.histogram` is not good: it returns you only the countings for each category

Answer (score 4):

A fast way to get the assignments in numpy is using `np.digitize`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

You'd still have to split the resulting assignments up into groups. If `x` or `y` is multidimensional, you will have to flatten the arrays first. You could then get the unique bin assignments, and then iterate over those in conjunction with `np.where` to split the the assigments up into groups. This will probably be faster if the number of bins is much smaller than the number of elements that need to be binned.

As a somewhat trivial example that you will need to tweak/elaborate on for your particular problem (but is hopefully enough to get you started with with a numpy solution):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.normal(size=(50,))

In [3]: b = np.linspace(-20,20,50)

In [4]: assign = np.digitize(x,b)

In [5]: assign
Out[5]: 
array([23, 25, 25, 25, 24, 26, 24, 26, 23, 24, 25, 23, 26, 25, 27, 25, 25,
       25, 25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 26, 24, 23, 25, 26, 26, 24, 24, 26, 27, 24,
       25, 24, 23, 23, 26, 25, 24, 25, 25, 27, 26, 25, 27, 26, 26, 24])

In [6]: uid = np.unique(assign)

In [7]: adict = {}

In [8]: for ii in uid:
   ...:     adict[ii] = np.where(assign == ii)[0]
   ...:     

In [9]: adict
Out[9]: 
{23: array([ 0,  8, 11, 25, 36, 37]),
 24: array([ 4,  6,  9, 24, 29, 30, 33, 35, 40, 49]),
 25: array([ 1,  2,  3, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 26, 34, 39, 41, 42, 45]),
 26: array([ 5,  7, 12, 19, 20, 23, 27, 28, 31, 38, 44, 47, 48]),
 27: array([14, 32, 43, 46])}
```

For dealing with flattening and then unflattening numpy arrays, see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html

Comment: In my code I'm looping over the data only one time. In your code you have a loop on line 4 and random access at line 8. In addition remember `x` is an iterator not a np.array

Comment: @wiso, but there is a big difference between looping in python vs looping inside of a numpy method that is doing that looping on the data in c. Further, you can create an array from an iterator using `np.fromiter`. Time your method vs some version of the one I posted and see for yourself which is faster. I'm just offering a suggestion

Comment: by the way, in the final dictionay I want the x values, not the indexes

Comment: @wiso, no offense, but you should not expect a full solution spelled out for you. It is **very** simple to use the indices to extract the values. I'm providing a framework for you to think about a numpy solution. Some work on your part will be required. . .

Comment: you're right about the speed, the point is that I'm doing multidimensional binning, so the number of total bins can be ~100 and the number of items ~1E6

Comment: Also, for multidimensional conversion and binning see the following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257619/numpy-interconversion-between-multidimensional-and-linear-indexing

Answer (score 0):

`np.searchsorted` is your friend. As I read somewhere here in another answer to the same topic, it's currently a good bit faster than digitize, and does the same job.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html